# What is causing these whitespace problems on Mac OS X bash?

Tags: macos, bash, xargs

I am trying to untar several files at once (I know I can do it differently but I want to make this work because it should work).
So I do:

```
ls -1 *.gz | xargs tar xf
```

This produces one command from xargs with all files, and fails. -1 is optional - fails the same way without it.

In fact,

```
ls -1 *.gz | xargs -t echo
echo host1_logs.tar.gz host2_logs.tar.gz host3_logs.tar.gz host5_logs.tar.gz
host1_logs.tar.gz host2_logs.tar.gz host3_logs.tar.gz host5_logs.tar.gz
```

I tried unsetting IFS, setting it to newline. 
How do I make xargs on Mac OS X actually work?

<s>Bonus question, in light of linebreak/loop problems I had with other commands before I wonder if Mac terminal is just broken and I should replace all utilities with GNU.</s>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `-n` argument to force `xargs` to run the given command with only a single argument:

```
ls -1 *.gz | xargs -n 1 echo
```

Otherwise, it tries to use each line from the input as a separate argument to the same invocation of the command.

Note that this will fail if any of the matched file names contain newlines, since `ls` has no way of producing output that distinguishes such names from a sequence of newline-free file names. (That is, there is no option to `ls` similar to the `-print0` argument to `find`, which is commonly used in pipelines like `find ... -print0 | xargs -0` to guard against such file names.)

---

Your question implies that you realize that you could do something like:

```
for f in *.gz; do
    tar xf "$f"
done
```

which is unlikely to be noticeably slower than any attempt at using `xargs`. In each case the process of spawning multiple `tar` processes is likely to outweigh any differences in looping in `bash` vs the internal loop in `xargs`.

Comment: thanks! Yeah, this works. I do realize I could do a loop but xargs is usually faster to type

Answer (score 0):

Basically you are passing all filenames to `tar` at once, which is not what you want as you have noticed. The above `xargs -n 1` answer is neater, but you could also use the **-I** flag to run the tar command for each of the arguments (also useful for multi-parameter commands like `mv`or `cp`):

```
ls *.gz | xargs -I {} tar xzvf {}
```